# React Hook Form - supply a dynamic Yup resolver to useForm

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I am using React Hook Form and want to supply a validation schema. However, the validation schema will have to be keyed off of some question guids that are based on a Backend schema. This particular Backend schema is retrieved and stored in Redux so I do:

```
const content = useSelector(state => selectFormContent(state.form))

// Generate a validation schema based on the type of the question and key it by guid
const validationSchema = content.questions.reduce((acc, q) => {
    acc[q.guid] = lookup[q.type]
}, {})

const { handleSubmit } = useForm({
    resolver: useYupValidationResolver(yup.object(validationSchema))
})
```

If I `console.log` the `validationSchema`, I don't see the proper Yup validation objects even though the `content` appears to be loaded in with all the questions in place. If I happen to do something to trigger a state change, THEN the schema starts working.

I can't exactly put my `validationSchema` code in a `useEffect` because `useForm` needs it. Is there a way I can get my `validationSchema` working upon initial form load?